# JS loop replaces every value from the list, but it should replace only the one I'm changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, input

I have 2 lists of inputs. One has already loaded values. I want to be able to type something in the other list so it would appear in the first list and replace the already existing value.

```
<div class="primary-list">
  <input type="text" class="ingredient1" value="a11">
  <input type="text" class="ingredient2" value="a22">
  <input type="text" class="ingredient3" value="a33">
  <input type="text" class="ingredient4" value="">
  <input type="text" class="ingredient5" value="x00123">
  <input type="text" class="ingredient6" value="">
  ... 
  (24 inputs total)
</div>

<div class="name-calc-col">
  <input type="text" class="name-calc1">
  <input type="text" class="name-calc2">
  <input type="text" class="name-calc3">
  <input type="text" class="name-calc4">
  <input type="text" class="name-calc5">
  <input type="text" class="name-calc6">
  ... 
  (24 inputs total)
</div>
```

```
$(".name-calc-col").children().on('input', function(){
    var name = [];
    
    for (let x = 1; x <= 24; x++) {
        name[x] = $(".name-calc" + x).val();
        name[x] = name[x] ? name[x] : "";

        $(".ingredient" + x).val(name[x]); 
    }
});
```

When I type something in the `.name-calc-col` input its value replaces `.ingredient(x)` value as it should, but it also deletes every already existing value (in the primary-list inputs) that were there before (so it won't delete the value that was given from the `.name-calc-col` input - when I type something in `name-calc1` and `name-calc2`, it will replace `ingredient1, ingredient2` values as it should and delete `ingredient3` a33 value).
I know that the loop takes EVERY value from the `.name-calc-col` list (also the empty ones) and replaces the values from the other list.

How can I make it so it won't replace all of the values for the list, but only the one I'm changing?

Comment: you can refer to the current element inside your event callback as `$(this)`

Comment: I know, I've been trying to do that with $(this), but can't figure it out.

Comment: `name[x] = name[x] ? name[x] : "";` is unnecessary because it's the same as `name[x] = name[x]`

Comment: Extract the "id" (`x`) from the class name or use [`$.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$(this)` to access the current element. This approach explicitly sets the target's class inside input elements:

```js
$(".name-calc-col").children().on('input', function() {
  // GET CURRENT INPUT VALUE
  const name = $(this).val();
  
  // GET TARGET ELEMENT CLASS
  const targetClass = $(this).attr('data-target')

  // SET VALUE ON .ingredient TARGET
  $("." + targetClass).val(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="primary-list">
  <input type="text" class="ingredient1" value="a11">
  <input type="text" class="ingredient2" value="a22">
  <input type="text" class="ingredient14" value="a33">
</div>

<hr>

<div class="name-calc-col">
  <input type="text" class="name-calc1" data-target="ingredient1">
  <input type="text" class="name-calc2" data-target="ingredient2">
  <input type="text" class="name-calc3" data-target="ingredient14">
</div>
```

Comment: When I type in, for example, name-calc15 it doesn't replace ingredient15 value, but something else's. Inputs in both lists can have no value.

Comment: use second approach, that way you can set exactly the class name you want to target

Comment: @Andreas true, I removed that snippet

Comment: The second solution (now the first one) works just fine. Thank you!